# Challanges with Pdf/a file for extraction using Python

Tags: python, text-extraction, pypdf, pdfa

We have some PDF/A files for extraction and when we try to use standard pdf extraction libraries, nothing is returned from program for entire page. same program is working perfectly fine for standard pdfs and retuning values.

Can anyone help how to convert them using python libraries.

Comment: *It is failing* isn't enough to go on. Show the Python code you are calling to do the conversion and the error message you get, with full stock trace.

Comment: You should give more details: which library, which kind of pdf ; pure text or a scan/picture ? and of cours your code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try pyPDF2?

```py
import PyPDF2 
pdfFileObj = open('example.pdf', 'rb')
```